# Arduino interrupt "CHANGE" not as sensitive as "RISING"

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I want to stop a motor (the "pulse" function) as soon as the light-barrier (connected to the wsensP Pin) detected something.

I made a first test with a "RISING interrupt":

```
void setup() { attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(wsensP), dropped, RISING);}
void dropped(){ wsensor = 1;}
void drop{
      wsensor = 0;
      while (!wsensor){
        pulse();
      }
}
```

and it worked perfectly : as soon as the drop falls into the light-barrier, the "pulse" function is not any more called.

But I wanted to have more detailed detection, and I switched to a "CHANGE" interrupt :

```
void setup() { attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(wsensP), detected, CHANGE); }
void detected(){
  wsensor = !wsensor;
  if (wsensor){
    rising = 1;
  } else {
    rising = 0;
  }
}
void drop() {
      rising = 0;
      while (!rising){
        pulse();
      }
}
```

and this does NOT stop at first rising edge !
I tried directly testing the "wsensor" variable (in the while condition). I added this "rising" boolean because I thought the wensor could have time to cycle 1 and 0 before the while condition has been tested....

I really can't understand what is wrong with my code. The ISR is minimal (setting 2 variables), the rest is also very simple...

Comment: Are the wsensor and rising volatile?

Comment: Yes. these 2 variables are declared as "volatile byte wsensor = 0;"

Comment: Then [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

I got it: the probleme is that the sensor may have a very short high level , so the variable "rising" is set to 0 before it is tested in the while condition.

Solution ==> delete the "else { rising = 0 }"

```
void setup() { attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(wsensP), detected, CHANGE); }
void detected(){
  wsensor = !wsensor;
  if (wsensor){
    rising = 1;
  }
// part of the code to delete : 
// else {
//    rising = 0;
//  }
}
void drop() {
      rising = 0;
      while (!rising){
        pulse();
      }
}
```